# How to create an array from multiple arrays in a mysqli fetch loop

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I am trying to create an array so i can print it in json format. I am querying a database using ***`mysqli`*** so and in the fetch loop sticking the returned information in an array, and trying to stick all of the arrays returned into one array and print that array in json format, but i cant seem to do it. here is my code, any help or insight would be vastly appreciated.

```
while($stmt->fetch())
{
$array .= ("title"=>$title,"date"=>$date,"body"=>$body)
}

print_r(json_encode($array));
```

but what is printed is

```
ArrayArrayArrayArrayArray
```

can anyone please help?

Comment: The problem is that to append to an array you don't you the `.=` operater, you use `$array[] = `.

Comment: You're not building an array. You're concatenating an array to a string, so PHP "helpfully" converts the array to a string for you, which means it just becomes the word `Array`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `[]` syntax to append a new element onto your array `$array`

```
$array = array();
while($stmt->fetch())
{
  $array[] = array("title"=>$title, "date"=>$date, "body"=>$body);
}
print_r(json_encode($array));
```

**Edited**.  Originally missed that this used MySQLi bound variables, rather than a fetched row.